# Android InAppBilling using Xamarin.InappBilling

Tags: android, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to implement InAppBilling in an android-app I'm developing using Xamarin.InAPPBilling. The problem I'm having is when i try to call the connection's billing handler to return a list of available products it doesn't return anything. So I'm wondering if there is something I have messed up in this very simple example or is it because I need to configure something with my developeraccount to be able to test it? Also, when I write an empty string where the key for the connection should be, I still are able to connect to the Google Play. Is this normal? Any help would be much appreciated!

```
namespace TestInapp
{
[Activity (Label = "TestInapp", MainLauncher = true)]

public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    Button button;
    IList<Product> _products;

    private InAppBillingServiceConnection _serviceConnection;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        Console.WriteLine ("Program starts");
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        _products = new List<Product> ();

        StartSetup ();

    }

    public void StartSetup()
    {
        // Create a new connection to the Google Play Service
        _serviceConnection = new InAppBillingServiceConnection (this, string.Empty);
        _serviceConnection.OnConnected += async () => {
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to GooglePlay");
            await GetInventory ();
        };
        _serviceConnection.Connect ();
    }

    async Task GetInventory()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Starting to find available products");

        _products = await _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.QueryInventoryAsync (new List<String>{
            "Produkt1",
            "Produkt2"
        }, ItemType.Product);

        Console.WriteLine ("Finished finding available products");

        if (_products == null) {
            Console.WriteLine ("No products available");
            return;
        } else  Console.WriteLine ("Products available");

        foreach (var p in _products) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine (p.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Ever figure this out bud? Using svn's code below, sample items don't come back in emulator but do on a real device. I've read that the emulators don't come with google play services and that's what causes this. However, I still can't get my actual items to return using the real product IDs over the reserved test ones.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things to setup before testing you own product (in de google play dev account). But you can test special test products before:

```
_products = await _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.QueryInventoryAsync (new List<string>     {
            ReservedTestProductIDs.Purchased,
            ReservedTestProductIDs.Canceled,
            ReservedTestProductIDs.Refunded,
            ReservedTestProductIDs.Unavailable
        }, ItemType.Product);
```

Comment: I have tried to use these reserved testproductsids but the program still say that no products are available. I mean, those productids will be in my _products list, right? Then the _products list shouldn't be returning null?

Comment: yeah. something else is wrong then. It should not return null. My advise is: setup the app in google play. upload an APK to google play. just set it in alpha mode. Then create the products in google play. This is the only way to really start testing it.

Comment: I added the apk to google play and went to the In-App products section, but it said that i didn't have any billingpermissions and I needed to add a new apk. I found out that you had to add <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" /> to the androidmanifest file. But when I add that apk to the Google Play and go to the In-App products section it still says that I dont have any billingpermissions in my app. any idea what I'm missing?